# Pandoc is not converting Stargazer output into Latex

Tags: r, markdown, pandoc, stargazer

I am using the following Stargazer code:

```
  library(stargazer)
  stargazer(r_1, r_2, r_3, r_4, title="Regression Results", align=TRUE)
```

I then knit my file and produce a .md markdown file.  I run pandocs from the `pandoc "myfile.md" -o output.pdf`

The document is correctly converted to LaTex, but Stargazer output is not converted into a proper table.  This is what I'm getting.
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like your table output has been commented out. Try setting the chunk output to `results="asis"` then rendering in pandoc.